Setting the SIGINT and SIGTERM timeout in ROS2
I have multiple ROS2 nodes being launched using a launch.py file.
One of the nodes, on shutdown, should call a function to save some data that takes >20 seconds. There are two things that I have tried.
1. Registering on_shutdown callback [Doesn't work]
The first one is registering a callback function rclcpp::on_shutdown(save_data_callback). This only works if the save_data_callback function doesn't take long to execute, e.g. printing something. However, as soon as the function takes >5 seconds, the execution stops, raising the error:
failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'

If I do a handler for SIGINT that takes >10 seconds, then the error becomes
failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGTERM', escalating to 'SIGKILL'

2. Modify the SIGINT and SIGTERM timeout [Works, but impractical]
The other alternative, is to directly modify the timeout for the signal handlers in the file /opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/actions/execute_process.py
Changing the default values:
        sigterm_timeout: SomeSubstitutionsType = LaunchConfiguration(
            'sigterm_timeout', default=30),
        sigkill_timeout: SomeSubstitutionsType = LaunchConfiguration(
            'sigkill_timeout', default=30),

This works, but it doesn't seem to be very practical. Has anyone gone through this?

Given sigterm_timeout is a LaunchConfiguration, it should be possible to alter its value from the command line, instead of having to change the default value in the code.
I tried the following and it seems to work (although I did not test this with Foxy):
   ros2 launch test.launch.py sigterm_timeout:=30

